# Why doesn't sudo -i respect the sudoers file

Tags: linux, sudo

To ensure the proper PATH environment variable is setup, I am using the `sudo -i` options, but am finding that the `sudoers` file isn't being respected.

Here is my setup:

`/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults    env_reset

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user    ALL=(ALL) ALL
user    ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/chef-solo
```

Running `sudo chef-solo -v` doesn't prompt for a password. Running `sudo -i chef-solo -v` will prompt for a password.

Comment: What happens when you specify the full path: `sudo -i /usr/local/bin/chef-solo -v`

Comment: @MarkWagner it still asks for a password. Remove the `-i` and it goes through fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo -i` executes your shell, not the command. It passes the command to the shell.

Comment: More specifically, executes a shell as the targeted user. (No `-u` assumes root.) Either way, this sudoers file isn't granting this privileges with `NOPASSWD`.

Comment: Adding `user ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/bash` worked like a charm: no password prompt.

Answer (score 0):

For sudo -i to work without a password, the rule using the alias ALL as the command to run needs the NOPASSWD flag.

Policy may prohibit this from being used for any command which may run as root (including su). This used to be true in my environment but is no longer; the rationale behind the change is that it is preferable for an already authenticated individual to run commands as root without a password than to rely on a service account to do so.

To switch accounts without using su, use NOPASSWD in conjunction with the non-root run-as user, as in the following rule:

%group ALL=(user) NOPASSWD: ALL

This then permits the use of both "sudo -iu user" and "sudo -u user command and args".